# get total sum per year from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables in my database that are `sales` and `purchases`, I would like to obtain the total amount per year of both tables in a single consultation. The structure of the tables looks more or less like this:

```
|    sales   | |  purchases | 
|------------| |------------|
| sales_id   | | purch_id   |
| date       | | date       |
| amount     | | amount     |
| account    | | account    |
```

At the moment I have the following code only for sales, but I need to have the total per year of both tables in a single query

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as year, SUM(amount) AS year_total 
FROM sales
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Comment: Do you mean a total combined by the 2 totals?

Comment: no, just a total for each table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support `full join`.  So, I would recommend `union all`/`group by`:

```
select year(date), sum(sale_amount) as sales, sum(purchase_amount) as purchases
from ((select date, amount as sale_amount, 0 as purchase_amount
       from sales
      ) union all
      (select date, 0, amount
       from purchases
      )
     ) sp
group by year(date);
```

This will return rows for all years in the data, even if there are no sales or purchases.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the related  subquery

```
select t1.year, ifnuLL(t1.year_total_sales,0), ifnull(t2.year_total_purchases,0)
from (
  SELECT YEAR(date) as year, SUM(amount) AS year_total_sales
  FROM sales
  GROUP BY YEAR(date)
) t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT YEAR(date) as year, SUM(amount) year_total_purchases
  FROM purchases
  GROUP BY YEAR(date)
)  t2 on t1.year = t2.year
```

and if you have some missing  years in one of the tables  you could use  left on the uion for the years

```
    select t3.year, t1.year_total_sales, t2.year_total_purchases
    from (
    select year(date) year 
    from sales
    union 
    select year(date)
    from purchases
    ) t3 
    left join (
      SELECT YEAR(date) as year, SUM(amount) AS year_total_sales
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY YEAR(date)
    ) t1 ON t3.year = t1.year
    LEFT  JOIN (
      SELECT YEAR(date) as year, SUM(amount) year_total_purchases
      FROM purchases
      GROUP BY YEAR(date)
    )  t2 on t3.year = t2.year
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I just tried it and it works, but I realized something, I will not take into account the records where the year is not present in both, for example: if I have records of purchases in 2020 and I still do not have records of sales In that year, he will not take those records into account. Is it possible that this information is also present ?, and if one of the two tables does not have a record for that year, that a 0 is shown as a total?